# Full-round action and Heroic Surge Feat

Tags: d20-system, star-wars-saga-edition

I am playing Star wars d20. My character is a soldier who can do multiple attacks as a [full round action](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm):

> **Full-Round Action.**
>
> A full-round action consumes all your effort during a round. The only movement you can take during a full-round action is a 5-foot step before, during, or after the action. You can also perform free actions (see below).

I also have the [Heroic Surge feat](https://www.d20resources.com/modern.d20.srd/feats/heroic.surge.php#:%7E:text=Benefit%3A%20The%20character%20may%20take,more%20than%20once%20per%20round.):

> **Heroic Surge**
>
> Benefit: The character may take an extra move action or attack action in a round, either before or after the character's regular actions. The character may use Heroic Surge a number of times per day depending on his or her character level (as shown below), but never more than once per round.

Could I do a Full-round action such as doing multiple attacks and then use Heroic Surge to move?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you take a full-round action, ordinarily, that “consumes all your effort during a round,” and the only other actions you can perform are free actions.¹

But Heroic Surge allows you to take an “extra” action, above and beyond that which you could ordinarily perform. That means yes, you can use your move or attack action after performing your full-round action. You could also use Heroic Surge first, planning to use a full-round action after using your extra action.

The point is that d20 System is an “exception-based ruleset,” which means you have general rules—such as those for full-round actions and for the actions everyone always gets in a typical turn—and then you have exceptions—such as those provided by Heroic Surge. Exceptions, by definition, violate the general rules in some specified way: they let you do something you ordinarily could not. (As one developer put it, they are a form of “sanctioned cheating.”)

Since d20 System is an exception-based ruleset, it is entirely normal for a specific thing (Heroic Surge) to contradict a general thing (full-round action rules), and we would not expect the rules for full-round actions to have an explicit mention of an exception like Heroic Surge. So the fact that full-round action uses pretty absolute language (“***all*** your effort”) doesn’t matter: Heroic Surge is an exception to that rule.

1. <sub>And, implicitly, a swift action if Star Wars d20 uses those, since those can be performed any time you can perform a free action so long as you haven’t already used one in the same turn.</sub>